# Why does Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider fail to cast to DbContext?

Tags: breeze, dbcontext

I'm using breeze to access data via an entity-framework server -- basically the default for breeze.  In my tests, I get the following runtime server error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SLN.Controllers.Context' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.
    at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.get_Context()
```

This is very odd since 1) my SLN.Controllers.Context class does subclass System.Data.Entity.DbContext and 2) I don't get this error in the product (non-test) environment.

Note that the error comes from the EFContextProvider class of Breeze.WebApi.dll which provides much of the server implementation.  EFContextProvider class has a generic parameter which I passed as SLN.Controllers.Context.  The EFContextProvider instance must instantiate my Context (since I don't) and then it must try to cast it to System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

How could this cast fail?  How can it work in non-test, but fail in test?

UPDATE

Per request, here are the parts of my code that are related to the runtime error.

```
public class Context : DbContext {...}

[BreezeController]
public class TruDBController : ApiController
{
    private class ContextProvider : EFContextProvider<Context>
    {
       ...
    }

    private readonly EFContextProvider<Context> _contextProvider = new ContextProvider();

    private EFContextProvider<Context> Provider 
    {
        get {return _contextProvider;}
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Models.Table1> Table1()
    {
        // error occurs on get of Context from Provider
        return Provider.Context.Table1;
    }
}
```

The cast is in the breeze [EFContextProvider](https://raw.github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/master/Breeze.WebApi/EFContextProvider.cs) class Context property:

```
public T Context {
  get {
    if (_context == null) {
      _context = CreateContext();
      // Disable lazy loading and proxy creation as this messes up the data service.
      if (typeof(ObjectContext).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
        var objCtx = (ObjectContext)(Object)_context;
        objCtx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      } else {
        var dbCtx = (DbContext)(Object)_context; // HERE??
        dbCtx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        dbCtx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      }
    }
    return _context;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where the cast is occurring in your controller?

Comment: As you are down in the weeds, what **is the type** of `_context` coming out of `CreateContext()` when it fails?

Comment: I downloaded the source for the breeze DLL.  I added that project to my solution.  My tests ran successfully!  So, as long as I build the breeze DLL, my tests pass.  But they fail if I use the pre-built DLL.  Why is that?  Maybe due to different versions of EntityFramework DLL.  Although that doesn't explain why I don't get an error when running as a non-test.  I guess I need to decide whether I want to always build the breeze DLL.